# How to employ BackdropScaffoldState.offset correctly to offset front contentlayer of compose BackdropScaffold

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-scaffold

My current android applications main screen contains a `androidx.compose.material.BackdropScaffold`. The backdrop looks great and functions exactly as it says on the tin.

however I have an issue with the `frontLayerContent` which contains a list of items.

I allow the user to interact with the `frontLayerContent` list while the backdrop is revealed, the issue is with the backdrop in the revealed state the user cannot scroll down to see the last item in the `frontLayerContent` list.

The solution to this issue is to use `backdropState.offset` in the `modifier` of the `frontLayerContent` which I obtain as follows:-

```
val backdropState = rememberBackdropScaffoldState(initialValue = BackdropValue.Concealed)
var offset by (backdropState.offset as MutableState)
```

and set as follows:-

```
onBackdropReveal = {
                if (!backdropState.isAnimationRunning) {
                    scope.launch {
                        if (backdropState.isConcealed) {
                            offset = backdropState.offset.value
                            backdropState.reveal()
                        } else {
                            offset = backdropState.offset.value
                            backdropState.conceal()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

and make the offset value available to other composables with:-

```
frontLayerContent = {
            CompositionLocalProvider(LocalBackdropStateOffset provides offset) {
                frontLayerContent()
            }
        }
```

Then in my `frontLayerContent` I retrieve the offset value as use as follows:-

```
val context = LocalContext.current
val offset = LocalBackdropStateOffset.current

Scaffold(
    topBar = { Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(0.dp)) },
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
) { paddingValues ->


    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .offset { IntOffset(x = 0, y = -offset.toInt()) },
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
    ) {
        LazyVerticalGrid(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp),
            columns = GridCells.Adaptive(125.dp),
            contentPadding = paddingValues,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
            content = {
                items(state.size) { index ->
```

this solution is close to what is required, however it looks as though I have made a mistake somewhere as my `frontLayerContent` list is always vertically offset even when the backdrop is concealed. In fact revealing or concealing the backdrop does not change the amount of offset of my `frontLayerContent` list.

how do I fix this issue?

how can I correctly set the `frontLayerContent` list vertical offset depending on whether the backdrop is concealed or revealed?

**UPDATE**

I only need to "fix" when the backdrop is revealed. therefore i need a conditional configuration of my `frontLayerContent` `Modifier.offset(y = -offset)`

how are you supposed to use the `backdropState.offset` value when correcting the `frontLayerContent` offset?
as the compose coordinate systems origin is the top left hand corner `(x = 0, y = 0)` and `y` dimension increases down the screen and `x` dimension increases Left to Right. when the backdrop is revealed the offset is a value (on my pixel 5) of approx `600.dp` and concealed value of approx `300.dp`. why is the concealed offset not `0.dp`? is this taking into account the screens `TopAppBar`?

**UPDATE (2)**
Heres a [GIF](https://media.giphy.com/media/6ifQVm9KzpBeW2liMs/giphy.gif) I made earlier

**UPDATE (3)**

This basic sample shows the problem i am having.
where have i made my mistake that stops me being able to scroll down
to see the complete last item when the backdrop is revealed?

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.material.BackdropScaffold
import androidx.compose.material.BackdropValue
import androidx.compose.material.ExperimentalMaterialApi
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Close
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Menu
import androidx.compose.material.rememberBackdropScaffoldState
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.IconButton
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBar
import androidx.compose.runtime.rememberCoroutineScope
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import com.elsevier.daisy.ui.theme.MyTheme
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    
    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    @ExperimentalMaterialApi
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val scaffoldState = rememberBackdropScaffoldState(initialValue = BackdropValue.Concealed)
            val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

            MyTheme {

                BackdropScaffold(
                    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
                    frontLayerScrimColor = Color.Unspecified,
                    frontLayerElevation = 5.dp,
                    gesturesEnabled = false,
                    appBar = {
                        TopAppBar(
                            title = { Text("Backdrop") },
                            navigationIcon = {
                                if (scaffoldState.isConcealed) {
                                    IconButton(
                                        onClick = {
                                            scope.launch { scaffoldState.reveal() }
                                        }
                                    ) {
                                        Icon(
                                            Icons.Default.Menu,
                                            contentDescription = "Menu"
                                        )
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    IconButton(
                                        onClick = {
                                            scope.launch { scaffoldState.conceal() }
                                        }
                                    ) {
                                        Icon(
                                            Icons.Default.Close,
                                            contentDescription = "Close"
                                        )
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        )
                    },
                    backLayerContent = {
                        Column {
                            Text(
                                text = "Menu Item 1", modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp), color = Color.White, style = TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                                    fontSize = 14.sp,
                                    color = Color.Black
                                )
                            )
                            Text(
                                text = "Menu Item 1", modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp), color = Color.White, style = TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                                    fontSize = 14.sp,
                                    color = Color.Black
                                )
                            )

                        }
                    },
                    frontLayerContent = {

                        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                            // Add 5 items
                            items(55) { index ->
                                Text(
                                    text = "Item: ${index + 1}",
                                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineLarge,
                                    modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp)
                                )
                            }
                        }


                    },
                    peekHeight = 60.dp,


                    ) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `the issue is with the backdrop in the revealed state the user cannot scroll down to see the last item in the frontLayerContent list.`?  In my experience with `BackdropScaffold` you can scroll down to last item. Would you mind posting a gif or image of issue you experience?

Comment: @Thracian I have added a GIF that shows my issue with backdrop frontlayercontent when the backdrop is revealed.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding a padding to the LazyColumn/LazyVerticalGrid itself rather than playing with the offset.

Given your example, I would simply add a conditional padding to the LazyColumn:

```
val padding = if (
    scaffoldState.isRevealed &&
    !scaffoldState.isAnimationRunning
) {
    64.dp
} else {
    0.dp
}

LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(bottom = padding)
) {
  // Your items here
}
```

I've used `64.dp` here but use whatever you feel is necessary according to your design.

If instead of using that magic number you want to calculate the height of the `backLayerContent` you can by using the `onGloballyPositioned` modifier and save the height in a state.

Add this before your `BackdropScaffold`

```
var backLayerContentHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
```

Get the `backLayerContent` height:

```
backLayerContent = {
    val localDensity = LocalDensity.current
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.onGloballyPositioned {
            val heightInPx = it.size.height
            val heightInDp = with(localDensity) { heightInPx.toDp() }
            backLayerContentHeight = heightInDp
        }
    ) {
       ...
    }
},
```

Then you can use this value for the padding:

```
val padding = if (
    scaffoldState.isRevealed &&
    !scaffoldState.isAnimationRunning
) {
    backLayerContentHeight
} else {
    0.dp
}
```

**Alternative to BackdropScaffold**

You may want to create a custom implementation to get a similar behavior without workarounds.

This custom component should help:

```
@Composable
fun CustomBackdropScaffold(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    appBar: @Composable () -> Unit,
    backLayerContent: @Composable () -> Unit,
    frontLayerContent: @Composable () -> Unit,
    isRevealed: Boolean,
) {
    Surface(modifier = modifier) {
        Column {
            appBar()

            AnimatedVisibility(
                visible = isRevealed,
                enter = expandVertically(
                    expandFrom = Alignment.Top,
                ),
                exit = shrinkVertically(
                    shrinkTowards = Alignment.Top,
                ),
            ) {
                backLayerContent()
            }

            frontLayerContent()
        }
    }
}
```

Here as an example of how to use it:

```
var isRevealed by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

CustomBackdropScaffold(
    appBar = {
        TopAppBar(
            title = { Text("Backdrop") },
            navigationIcon = {
                if (!isRevealed) {
                    IconButton(
                        onClick = {
                            isRevealed = true
                        }
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            Icons.Default.Menu,
                            contentDescription = "Menu"
                        )
                    }
                } else {
                    IconButton(
                        onClick = {
                            isRevealed = false
                        }
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            Icons.Default.Close,
                            contentDescription = "Close"
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    },
    backLayerContent = {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Menu Item 1",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                color = Color.White,
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    fontSize = 14.sp,
                    color = Color.Black
                )
            )
            Text(
                text = "Menu Item 1",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                color = Color.White,
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    fontSize = 14.sp,
                    color = Color.Black
                )
            )
        }
    },
    frontLayerContent = {
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            // Add 5 items
            items(55, key = { it }) { index ->
                Text(
                    text = "Item: ${index + 1}",
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineLarge,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    },
    isRevealed = isRevealed
)
```

Comment: that does work, however there are couple of features i am not happy with (i) i have to pick a magic number = 64.dp or whatever fixes on any android device (ii) why does this issue exist for backdropscaffold at all? why is it the developers responsibility to fix this when i feel this should be "built in" to the backdrop component

Comment: Added an example to calculate the height instead of using a magic number. 

No idea about issue 2. I've never used this component so I'm not really sure if it's the right tool for the job. Looking at your GIF, I would probably create by own toolbar with the required feature, as seems quite easy to do (unless I've missunderstood something).

Comment: this is a really nice improvement, however i still feel like developers shouldnt have to  have the responsibility to fix this issue which is starting to smell like a bug in the backdrop component

Comment: Looking at the design specification of material design, seems to be an intentional design decision https://m2.material.io/components/backdrop#behavior

Comment: I've added an example using a custom component rather than relying on the default backdrop. It's not as complete API-wise as the built-in component but should be good enough as an alternative to your issue.

Comment: nice work, that deserves the bounty ;)